# add a radio button in RichTextArea

Tags: java, gwt

There is a RichTextArea

```
private final RichTextArea rta = new RichTextArea();
```

and I'd like when I press an asterisk to add a radio button in this RichTextArea.

I wrote

```
 if(event.getCharCode()=='*')
   {            
     RadioButton radio0 = new RadioButton("group0", "");
     HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
     hp.add(radio0);
     RootPanel.get().add(hp);
   }
```

it creates a radio button out of the RTA but I can't add it in the RTA, specifically where the cursor is and without the asterisk.

Any idea how to do that?
Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you really add a radio button to richtext area!!!
I really don't know
But if you can then the answer may be:
You have added radio button to root panel and not richtext area.

Comment: Yes I can and I did it that way but I don't know how to add it in the richTextArea because rta doesn't support the add() method or any other relevant method in order to add it. If anyone know how to do that please, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: if(event.getCharCode()=='*')
{            
rta.setHTML("<input type=radio name=name value=1>"); } I create and add the radio button into the RichTextArea but in firefox is not clickable. In Chrome works fine. Any idea please?